# Automatically refresh an image in ubuntu raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, raspberry-pi2

I am streaming and writing an image to a particular location in a raspberry pi. Every time a new image comes it overwrites the previous one. Now if i keep that image file open, it does not get automatically updated.I have to close and reopen it for the update to happen.Is there anyway i can automatically refresh it.

I tried implementing a python code to continuously read and show the image. But still i have to refresh the window for the image to get updated. Below is the code that i used.

```
img = cv2.imread("Filename",1)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Please suggest any alternatives. I just need to preview the stream.

Comment: I don't know about other image viewers, but eog (eye of gnome) refreshes the image once it changes

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple loop as you can call imshow repeatedly without destroying it.

```
while True: #Find something to get out of here
    img = cv2.imread("Filename",1)
    cv2.imshow('image', img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: How it's make refresh, It's shows the same frames continuously.

Answer (score 0):

due to opencv documenation:

> For example, waitKey(0) will display the window infinitely until any keypress (it is suitable for image display). waitKey(25) will display a frame for 25 ms, after which display will be automatically closed.

So you have to set time in milliseconds instead of 0.